# Why my grid texture won't apply to the object?

Tags: uv

I have my uv map set.
And set the material.
But why my object still white?

[image]
[image]

File:
[image]

Comment: how does your Shader Editor setup look like?

Comment: I have added the image you requested.

Comment: instead of a Background node (which I guess is for the world), try a Diffuse node

Comment: Not working either. So, I attach the file. Maybe you could take a look, if you had time.

Answer (score 2):

Choose a *Diffuse* node instead of *Background* (which I guess is used for the world):

[image]

In *Edit* mode, select all the face to which you want to assign the material, and in the *Material* panel, choose the material and click on *Assign*:

[image]